# Terraform multiple region aws_ses_domain_identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create a aws_ses_domain_identity resource in multiple regions but as far as I can see, this is only possible by changing the region of the AWS provider.

I've attempted to use a for_each with no luck. I then want to create a aws_route53_record from the verification_tokens. I suspect this also won't work.

Ultimately, I'm aiming for creating an SES domain identity and corresponding Route 53 verification records for the regions specified in a variable (ses_regions).

Code:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "eu-central-1"
  region  = "eu-central-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias   = "us-west-2"
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

variable "ses_regions" {
  description = "The aws region in which to operate"
  default = {
    region1 = "us-west-2"
    region2 = "eu-central-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "example" {
  for_each = var.ses_regions

  provider = each.value
  domain = var.ses_domain
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "example_amazonses_verification_record" {
  for_each = aws_ses_domain_identity.example.verification_token

  zone_id = var.zone_id
  name    = "_amazonses.${var.ses_domain}"
  type    = "TXT"
  ttl     = "600"
  records = each.value
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Invalid provider configuration reference

  on .terraform/modules/ses/main.tf line 8, in resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "example":
   8:   provider = aws.each.value

The provider argument requires a provider type name, optionally followed by a
period and then a configuration alias.
```

Comment: You would probably be better off creating a module for ses validation and calling it multiple times using different providers in your root terraform config.

Comment: Yeah I've pretty much come to that conclusion. It looks like provider blocks with for_each isn't supported yet - https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19932. I just want to avoid having to hard code the regions in provider blocks and have all the config (i,e, regions to use) held in a variable - we use terragrunt